# Extracting the actual date information of a partition based on date field in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

I have a feed table which is using interval partitioning(Monthly partition) to hold 3 years of historic data with the partition key as a date field of the table.  We need to drop partitions older than 3 years(36 months).

While dropping the partition I would like to display a message to the user telling the month and year of the partition to be dropped. To get the month info, I'll have to use the HIGH_VALUE column of USER_TAB_PARTITIONS table since the partition_name is system generated like 'SYSP###' giving no month information.

The value in HIGH_VALUE column is like:

```
TO_DATE(' 2011-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
```

I am unable to extract '2011-01-01' from above string using **SUBSTR/REGEXP_SUBSTR**.

I was using below query just to check if I can extract the required info:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('TO_DATE(' 2011-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')',10, 10 )  FROM DUAL;

The error I am getting is:
Error: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

I am not sure if I am doing some silly mistake here.

Would aqppreciate your kind assistance/any pointer/alternate way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Vinod

Comment: Could you post the full sql statement?

Comment: Yes sure.
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('TO_DATE(' 2011-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')',10, 10 )  FROM DUAL;

The error I am getting is:

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding a comment.

Comment: Why `regexp_substr` instead of just `substr`? (Though with that space in there, it needs to start at position 11, not 10?)

Comment: @Patrick Hofman I  have updated the question.

Comment: `high_value` is a `long`, of course, which makes life a bit harder, unless you're already pulling it into PL/SQL variable as part of your drop process. You might find the answers on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5536830/266304) helpful.

Comment: @Alex Poole Yes, You are right about the position.

Comment: @Alex Poole Also, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing doesn't make much sense to me.

You try to apply a regular expression on a `date`, instead of a `varchar`.

You could try this:

```
select to_char( TO_DATE( ' 2011-01-01 00:00:00'
                       , 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
                       , 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'
                       )
              , 'yyyy-mm-dd'
              )
FROM   DUAL
```

If you want to extract the value from the statement try this:

```
select substr( 'TO_DATE('' 2011-01-01 00:00:00'', ''SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'', ''NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'')',10, 11 )
FROM   DUAL
```

Note I changed the last `10` in your statement to `11` too.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the query which I was trying by using (') as a escape character.

Comment: Not as of now. This should be fine. But definitely reach out to you in case I stuck somewhere else. Thanks once again.

Comment: @VinodYadav: Please don't forget to mark the question as answered if the answer was helpful. See the [FAQ#why-vote].